# SOQL used in aura enabled method returns values in user's language

Tags: soql, translation, aura-enabled

`SELECT Profile.Name FROM User WHERE Id = :userId LIMIT 1`returns `Profile.Name` in user's languague. The query is placed inside aura enabled method. For ex. an user with language set up as Dutch returns `Systeembeheerder` for `System Adminstrator` profile. Is this working as expected? If yes, then how can we make sure that the query result is in English?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if that's expected, and find it quite surprising, but if you want to force a specific language for an operation, then Visualforce provides an easy way to do that. It supports a language parameter in the `<apex:page>` tag that means all code in the execution context runs using the specified language, even if that code is standard (i.e. there's no custom controller here). It even translates things like field describe info.

There might be other better options for Lightning, but at worst you can use this to get the profile name in any language you want using a GET request:

```
<apex:page standardController="User" language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lang}">
    <apex:outputText value="{!User.Profile.Name}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Calling this with a user Id and language code will return the profile name, for example in one of my scratch orgs:

`/apex/ProfileName?lang=fr&id=005E1000005A9K5IAK` returns "Administrateur système"
`/apex/ProfileName?lang=en&id=005E1000005A7tQIAS` returns "Analytics Cloud Integration User"

Comment: Thanks Matt! That's good to know! We are dealing with this in aura component. Even if we login as the user and run the same query in dev console, it return the translated profile name in user's language